# Validation messages are not showing in cakephp 2.4.x

Tags: php, cakephp

Here is my validation rule in User.php

```
public $validate = array(
    'username' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'User name is required'
        ),
        'alphaNumeric'=>array(
            'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
            'required' => true,
            'message' => 'Alphabets and numbers only'
        )
    ))
```

and this is my view page code

```
<?php
      echo $this->Form->create('User');
      echo $this->Form->input('username', array('label' => 'Username'));
      echo $this->Form->input('email', array('label' => 'Email'));
      echo $this->Form->input('password', array('label' => 'Password'));
      echo $this->Form->submit('Sign Up');
      echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

Here is my controller code

```
public function register() {
$this->layout = 'starter';
//debug($this->validationErrors);
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->User->validates()) {
        $this->User->save($this->request->data);
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Please login your account'));
        $this->redirect('/users/login');
      } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
      }
 }
}
```

but validation message is not showing. What is wrong in my code?...

Comment: do you have changed your layout ?

Comment: To help debug you can try `debug($this->validationErrors);` to see if the validation is even setting the errors.

Comment: Yes. I have changed layout from default cake.css and debug($this->validationErrors); showing null

Comment: Well, there you have it, no validation errors, so nothing to display. If there _should_ be validation errors, then try to debug why there aren't, or add more info to your question (how is the data being saved, which options are used, what data is actually passed, etc) so that someone is able to understand what exactly is happening in your application.

Comment: Your code is full of wrong doing, there is no method called `validate()`, only `validates()`, with a trailing `s`, however for this to work at all you'd have to [**set the data first**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html).

Comment: Also you are not evaluating the return value of `Model::save()`, which is kinda essential for saving data. And placing `debug($this->validationErrors)` _before_ actually validating will of course not show any errors. Please check the cookbook on how to save properly: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html#adding-posts | http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong.

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->User->validates()) {
        $this->User->save($this->request->data);
```

this is not how it could ever work as the data is not passed prior to validation.

You need to first pass the data, then validate, then optionally save (or save and validate together):

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {}
```

**or**, careful not to retrigger validation twice:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->User->set($this->request->data);
    if ($this->User->validates()) {
        $success = $this->User->save(null, array('validate' => false));
```

But that is documented.

The latter only makes sense if you really need to do this in two steps.

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you have written you have changed layout page.It may you miss

```
<?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
```

this line.Add this line in your view/layouts/yourlayout.ctp file.

Comment: Finaly I got it.There is one more code to add on controller.    $this->User->set($this->request->data); After it worked

Answer (score 0):

Disable HTML5 `required` in your view page code

```
<?php
  echo $this->Form->create('User');
  echo $this->Form->input('username', array('label' => 'Username','required'=>'false'));
  echo $this->Form->input('email', array('label' => 'Email','required'=>'false'));
  echo $this->Form->input('password', array('label' => 'Password','required'=>'false'));
  echo $this->Form->submit('Sign Up');
  echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```